# How to stop macOS Safari from crashing iOS Amazon Prime

Tags: macos, ios, ipad, safari

If I'm using the Amazon Prime video app on my iPad, and then I open or interact with macOS Safari on my iMac, Amazon Prime crashes every time.  It will often fail to restart on the iPad until I completely close macOS Safari.  What is the root of this problem and how can I work-around it?

I thought that perhaps AirPlay or Sidecar were contributing to the problem, and disabled Bluetooth on the iPad, but that doesn't solve the problem.   My other theory is that Amazon Prime may have an embedded version of WebKit and something within that is attempting to synchronize via iCloud services, but I've found no concrete evidence of that or how to manage it.

In short, I can't use Safari on my iMac and watch Amazon Prime on my iPad at the same time.  It's a weird bug.

Comment: I just tried this and had no problem.  I watched an old TV show on my iPad and surfed the internet. I then quit Safari and restarted it. The show played fine throughout it all with not even a glitch.

Comment: what system are you running on iMac?   i'm running High Sierra.

Comment: Catalina 10.15.3 and whatever the very latest version of macOS, iOS, and the Amazon Prime iOS app is today.

Comment: However, I've noticed this odd bug for months if not a year or so, even before Catalina, but today it just annoyed me enough to ask the community.

Comment: must be something with Catalina I suppose.  There have been many questions on this site referencing problems encountered with Catalina. Have you checked an Apple site to see if there are other reports? Maybe someone will post later about this.

Comment: Was that with Mojave?

Comment: Just to help isolate the issue, have you tried opening Safari with WiFi disabled on your Mac to see if it still crashes?

Comment: My iMac doesn't have WiFi enabled. So, I've eliminated WiFi and Bluetooth.  I ran the iMac and the iPad through a proxy to satisfy my curiousity, to see if I could spot messaging of any sort directly between the two.   The only traffic I noticed was that the iPad would send a keep-alive connection to fls-na.amazon.com and a moment later the mac would also connect to gateway.icloud.com with a keep-alive.  This happens every time I launch macOS Safari, and the order of connections and the crash are opposite of what I'd expect.  ie. I expected some sort of traffic to send from the mac first.

Comment: It seems to me that if all the radios are off on your Mac, trying to sync with iCloud wouldn’t be the issue since iCloud would have no idea that you opened Safari on your Mac.

Comment: @RyDev I'm not entirely sure how syncing works.  If the proxy revealed that both devices were talking to the same backend service, gateway.icloud.com, I'd be more inclined to think it was an iCloud related issue; however, Prime sends a connection to AWS and the Mac sends a connection to iCloud, and then the Prime app crashes.  If the iMac doesn't have Safari open, Prime on the iPad runs with no problems.

Comment: I reset my iMac and re-installed the latest macOS to a freshly formatted drive and immediately got a better clue about what is happening.  It's something to do with Handoff.   A HandOff Safari icon will bounce from the dock when I attempt to watch a show on the iPad.  It'll bounce once and then the Amazon Prime on the iPad will crash.  If I very quickly click the HandOff icon I can see that it references whatever movie or show that was about to play on the iPad.  So, I think that supports my earlier theory that Amazon Prime Video has an embedded WebKit instance and the implementation is buggy.

Comment: I am having the same problem now, is there any solutions?

Comment: No solutions.  iOS, macOS, and probably Amazon Prime have been updated since I posted here, and the problem still happens.  I haven't had time to investigate it further, but it seemingly is related to HandOff + Amazon Prime Video's usage of Webkit within the app.